# How to find $x\ge0$ such that $Ax=b$ and show, using Farkas' lemma, the solution is unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I know that Farkas' lemma certifies the feasibility of a system $Ax=b$ with $x>=0$.

Now suppose it's feasible. How do I find a solution x and under what conditions on A and b do I know the solution is unique?